# What are All the ways we can run a scala code in Apache-Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I know there is two ways to run a scala code in Apache-Spark:

```
1- Using spark-shell
2- Making a jar file from our project and Use spark-submit to run it
```

Is there any other way to run a scala code in Apache-Spark? for example, can I run a scala object (ex: object.scala) in Apache-Spark directly?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"for example, can I run a scala object (ex: object.scala) in Apache-Spark directly?"* Why are the other way not enough for the use case at hand? What's that?

Comment: @jacek-laskowski I don't mean that these two ways are not enough. Currently, I'm learning Apache Spark and I want to know all ways I can run my codes. I want to know can I run my scala code without changing it to Jar files? this is for accelerate testing operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Using spark-shell

## 2. Making a jar file from our project and Use spark-submit to run it

## 3. Running Spark Job programmatically

```
String sourcePath = "hdfs://hdfs-server:54310/input/*";

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TestLineCount");
conf.setJars(new String[] { App.class.getProtectionDomain()
        .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() });
conf.setMaster("spark://spark-server:7077");
conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<String> log = sc.textFile(sourcePath);

JavaRDD<String> lines = log.filter(x -> {
    return true;
});

System.out.println(lines.count());
```

Scala version:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    Logger.getLogger("okka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    val logFile = "/tmp/logs.txt"

    val conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("Simple Application")
        .setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache

    println("line count: " + logData.count())
  }
}
```

for more detail refer to [this blog post](http://activeintelligence.org/blog/archive/getting-started-with-spark-local-standalone/).

Comment: Thanks for answer Milad. Your code is in java language but is there a same way for scala language? and second question is that how we must run codes like this (in scala language)?

Comment: There is no difference between Java and Scala API of Apache Spark. You need to to find the class file of Scala program and pass it to setJar method.